# Jquery DataTables = re-populating rows by code

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Using DataTables plugin,i want to manually repopulate the rows with fresh data (not thru the data.reload api)

So I need to flush the data and put new data into it..

What is thew proper way to do this?

Destroy and re-initiate the DataTable?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No need to destroy, just re-initialize the table.